# How to make difference in String[] between real strings and integer values?

Tags: java, string, integer

I'm developing an app where I have

```
String[][] datos;
```

I need to make a difference between all string and integer values there for one method.
for example:

```
datos[0][2]: "hi"
datos[1][1]: "3"
datos[2][2]: "a"
datos[3][0]: "25"
```

in this case I only need 3 and 25 values, but I can't make it doing

```
Integer.parseInt(datos[1][1]);
```

for each value.

In my code I only made specific cases, but I want to make all cases in the first if sentence.

```
for(int f=2;f<maxf;f++)
    for(int c=3;c<maxc;c++){
        if((datos[f][c]!= "A")&&(datos[f][c]!= "-")&&(datos[f][c]!= "")){
            nota= Integer.parseInt(datos[f][c]);
            if(nota>3)
                aprobados.set(f-2, aprobados.get(f-2)+1);
        }
    }
```

Comment: Aside: don't compare strings using `==`, use `equals`.

Comment: @AndyTurner I realized after publishing it xD

Comment: Where does `datos` come from? Is it just a random 2D array, in which some elements just happen to be integers? If you know the structure of the data, you can simplify the code used for parsing it significantly.

Comment: @MickMnemonic I can't know which cells of datos will be integers and which will be another string. That's why I'm trying to avoid Strings cells in for sentence. 

Until now I've changed if condition asking if parseInt value is in a range of possible number (1-10).

Comment: `parseInt()` throws `NumberFormatException` if the string can't be parsed as `int` - you could catch that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Create a new method aside :

```
public boolean isNumeric (String s){
    try{
        Double.parseDouble(s);
        return true;
    } catch (Exception e) {
        return false;
    }
}
```

This will return true if the cast is possible, otherwise false is returned

Comment: OP is parsing `int`s, not `double`s.

Comment: Aside from that this is horrible... Using a String[] is overall the wrong approach

Comment: @mickmnemonic is does not make a difference here. Vogel612 Show us how you would do it...

Comment: Unfortunately I do not speak portuguese or spanish or whatever that is, so I don't even know what exactly OP is doing there... but usually (as outlined in my answer) I'd use a POJO to properly line up the data

Answer (score 3):

I agree with the objections to using `String[][]` for mixed data.

However, if the OP does not have a choice, here is a variant of the test program that shows how to do it:

```
public class Test {
  public static void main(String[] args) {
    int maxf = 4;
    int maxc = 3;
    String[][] datos = new String[maxf][maxc];
    datos[0][2] = "hi";
    datos[1][1] = "3";
    datos[2][2] = "a";
    datos[3][0] = "25";

    for (int f = 0; f < maxf; f++)
      for (int c = 0; c < maxc; c++) {
        if (datos[f][c] != null) {
          try {
            int nota = Integer.parseInt(datos[f][c]);
            System.out.println(nota);
          } catch (NumberFormatException e) {
            // Deliberately empty
          }
        }
      }
  }
}
```

Comment: Thanks @PatriciaShanahan , I've used  String[] because it could be words or numbers in cells, that is user's choice. I didn't make a different Class "Data" because I think it would be useless apart of telling me if it is a numeric data or string data.

Answer (score 0):

Using a `String[]` is the wrong approach to this overall. Instead you should use a Class of your own so you don't have to worry about where in your array you have what now.

Answer (score 0):

You can check if a string contains only digits by using the regular expression "^[0-9]*$".
I would prefer not to use exception catching. I believe regex matching would be more efficient, like this:

```
public static void main(String []args){
    int maxf = 4;
    int maxc = 3;
    String[][] datos = new String[maxf][maxc];
    datos[0][2] = "hi";
    datos[1][1] = "3";
    datos[2][2] = "a";
    datos[3][0] = "25";

    for(int f = 0; f < maxf; f++){
        for(int c = 0; c < maxc; c++){
            if(datos[f][c] != null && datos[f][c].matches("^[0-9]*$")){
                int nota = Integer.parseInt(datos[f][c]);
                System.out.println("datos[f][c] = " + nota);
                // if(nota>3)
                //     aprobados.set(f-2, aprobados.get(f-2)+1);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Internally, `String.matches()` calls [`Pattern.matches()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/regex/Pattern.html#matches%28java.lang.String,%20java.lang.CharSequence%29), which again calls `Pattern.compile()`, which is _expensive_. On the other hand, `Integer.parseInt()` only examines the underlying character array of the `String`. So in this case, using the regex approach is probably more inefficient (and less readable).

Comment: You seem to be right. I thought that throwing exception would be slower, but when I actually compare the performance, the exception way seems faster. Thanks.